# Access a matrix rapidly

Tags: c++, c, performance

I need to access a two-dimensions matrix with a C++ code. If the matrix is `mat[n][m]`, I have to access (in a for-loop) these positions:

```
mat[x][y], mat[x-1][y-m-1], mat[x-1][y], mat[x][y-1]
```

At the next iteration I have to do:

```
x=x+1
```

And then, again:

```
mat[x][y], mat[x-1][y-m-1], mat[x-1][y], mat[x][y-1]
```

What could be the best way to have these positions nearest in memory to speedup my code?

Comment: how large is your matrix going to be (both dimensions and what the type of the elements is)? If its small enough to fit in L1 cache, < 16KB, then access patterns won't really matter.

Comment: The matrix is an int matrix (258x258 or 258x129), so it is between 130 and 160 Kb.

Comment: Did your profiler tell you that accessing the matrix is the bottleneck of your application? Have you tried parallelizing the loop?

Answer (score 1):

If you are iterating horizontally, arrange your matrix as mat[y][x], especially if it is an array of arrays (the layout of the matrix isn't clear in your answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provided sufficient information, it's hard to say which way is better.

You could try to unroll your loop for continuous memory access.

For example, read from `mat[x][y]` 4 times, then `mat[x-1][y-m-1]` 4 times, then `mat[x-1][y]` 4 times, then `mat[x][y-1]` 4 times. After that, you process the loaded 4 sets of data in one iteration.

I bet the bottleneck is not the memory access itself. It should be the calculation of memory address. This approach of memory access can be written in SIMD load so you could reduce 3/4 time cost of memory address calculating.

If you have to process your task sequentially, you could try not to use multidimensional subscribes. For example:

```
for( x=0; x<n; x++ )
    doSomething( mat[x][y] );
```

could be done with:

```
for( x=y; x<n*m; x+=m )
    doSomething( mat[0][x] );
```

In second way you avoided one `lea` instruction.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use SIMD in this case: I can't make the "work" on the subsequent four-set of cells if I have not completed the "work" on the previous ones.

Comment: I don't mean you have to use SIMD. You need to calculate your address in more efficient way. As my experience of profiling, in critical routine such 2D-array subscribes with addition and subtraction is killing performance.

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right, you loop through your entire array, although you only mention `x = x + 1` as an update (nothing for `y`). I would then see the array as one-dimensional, with a single counter `i` going from `0` to the total array length. Then the four values to access in each loop would be

```
mat[i], mat[i-S-m-1], mat[i-S], mat[i-1]
```

where `S` is the stride (rows or columns depending on your representation). This requires less address computations, regardless of memory layout. It also takes less index checks/updates because there's only one counter `i`. Plus, `S+m+1` is constant, so you could define it as such.